# Improving the design of a JPA polymorphic association

Tags: jpa, polymorphic-associations

I have the following **JPA entity hierarchy:**

[image: class diagram for jpa entities]

Upon logging in to the application a user has an instance of `UserAccount` in session; then depending on the concrete type of the organization associated to that `UserAccount` (`Admin`, `Business` or `Family`), a different dashboard/screen is displayed to the user e.g. if the user is a `Business`, then the dashboard for that business is displayed.

My concern with that design is that I have to do a `instanceof` check each time a user logs in so that I know which type of dashboard to display. I could also avoid that `instanceof` check by having a property in `UserAccount` such as `organizationType` (which would take one of three values) but then there would be redundant information.

Is there a way to improve my design? If so how?

Comment: Inheritance hierarchies of what is essentially bags of data (i.e. anaemic domain models) always seems a bad idea to me, which is why I tend to use them sparingly. Are there essential differences between the data requirements of the three organization types? If not, I'd seriously consider flattening the structure and using an `organizationType` property instead. If there are essential differences, and there are no *clients* of the `Organization` entity that know the exact class they are interacting with, you will have to use `instanceof` at *some* point anyway.

Comment: Alternatively, if you *really* want to avoid `instanceof`, you could, for instance, use the Visitor pattern that would build the appropriate `Dashboard` for a concrete `Organization` type (FTW if you ask me). If there are many operations that work with `Organization` but need to know the concrete type, they could be implemented in the form of Visitors as well

Answer (score 0):

Be greedy and get both, without redundancy.

Depending on the inheritance strategy, you may already have the `organizationType` info and you can expose it for free.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DTYPE")
public abstract class AbstractOrganization implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "DTYPE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected String organizationType;

    ...

}
```

the same applies also to the `JOINED` strategy.

Do not implement the `setOrganizationType` method.

Since a *discriminator* is **required** for simulating hierarchies with tables (except `TABLE_PER_CLASS` strategy), there's no redundancy and JPA provider will handle this attribute for you.